# Is the index related to predicate, or are they independent entitites?

Tags: database, predicate

It is a theoretical question I can't seem to get my head around. Is the index related to the predicate, and if yes, how? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicates are an Ed Codd, relational ideal.

Indexes have more to do with the physical implementation of the table.  They help make searches faster (e.g. B-tree representation).

Predicates can be mapped to WHERE clauses and indexes in actual implementations, but I think predicate is more abstract and theoretical.  It doesn't know or care about how you decide to implement the relation.  Predicate is still true whether you do a TABLE SCAN or index it properly.

Comment: So it does not deal with the actual implementation of the index?

Comment: I don't believe so.  Predicate doesn't presume anything about implementation.  When you implement, you'll add indexes for WHERE clauses to speed up searches (from O(n) to O(log(n)), and those are associated with predicates, but the idea of predicate is abstract, ideal.